# How to implement Fused Location Provider in Android Api level 23

Tags: android

i am trying to get continuous location updates in my app using Fused Location provider somehow it worked fine in Lollipop but in Marshmallow it is not showing any location update.

Below is my code.Plz let me know what i am ding wrong.

```
public class Gps extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

TextView lati, longi;
LocationRequest lr;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);

    lati = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lati);
    longi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longi);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    lr = LocationRequest.create();
    lr.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    lr.setInterval(1000);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{

                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, 1);

            return;
        }

    }
    else{

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, lr,this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(Gps.this, Locale.getDefault());

    String locality = null;
    String sub = null;

    try {

        List<Address> addrList;

        addrList = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 2);

        if (addrList.size() > 0) {

            Address adr = addrList.get(0);
            locality = adr.getLocality();
            sub = adr.getSubLocality();

            lati.setText(locality);
            longi.setText(sub);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {

        case 2:
            if(){
          }                
           else{

                  }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have no logic to request for location updates in your `onRequestPermissionsResult` function. Also, you are only requesting `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and not `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` even though you check for both.

**Edit:**

In your `onConnected` function, you never call `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates()` when you are on Marshmallow or above. Essentially you are just doing this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    if (/*No permissions*/) {
        //Request permissions
        return;
    }
    //Location updates are never requested here!!!
}
else {
    //Request location updates
}
```

When it should be something like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    if (/*No permissions*/) {
        //Request permissions
        return;
    }
}
//Request location updates
```

Comment: Thanks for telling now i added request for Coarse location too but how to request location updates in onRequestPermissionsResult plz let me know .

Comment: Call `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates()` in that function. Otherwise, in API 23+, it is never called.

Comment: i am trying to add LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGo‌​ogleApiClient, lr,this);   in OnRequestPermissionResult but is showing error saying add permission check but i've checked permission already.

Comment: Updated my answer. This is a better way than what I mentioned in the last comments.